# Twitter API v2 search stream with JAVA/Kotlin is not streaming return, when I use Curl works fine

Tags: java, api, kotlin, twitter, stream

I tried use this exemple and everything looks fine https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Filtered-Stream/FilteredStreamDemo.java
When the application is running, I post some tweets witch match my rules, nothing happens! Does someone know if I'm missing something?
PS.: When I execute direct CURL from terminal, the stream works fine.